# Deezer JS API returning Location:http://www.mydomain.com.br/dz/channel.html#token|exception|unknown

Tags: javascript, api, deezer

im doing the software to play deezer`s songs, and im using the Deezer Javascript API.

But when i use getStatus of user there is a error:

Deezer JS API returning:
**Location:http://www.mydomain.com.br/dz/channel.html#token|exception|unknown**

and the throw exception: 
**Uncaught An error has occured, please retry your action**

Or when i use login, the popup show the following error:
**"You must enter a valid redirect uri"**

What i need do to fix this errors?

Comment: You probably need to go to your developer account http://developers.deezer.com/myapps, then go to your app and set the domain properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to set the domain of your website, not the whole URL and it will work.